# React node app - is it better to store property is watched (item is watched) in frontend or backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a watchlist, where user can add items to. I want to either show add button or string 'item is already on watchlist'. is it better to store that isWatched prop on frontend or backend?
on frontend: I already do fetch watchlist. I can put make it global using for example context, then I could have an array of id's of watched items in my global store and pass it to components that checks 'isWatched'.
on backend: I could add it (isWatched prop) the to item in my product collection. then when user opens the product item, the prop isWatched is already there. no fetching needed.

What is good practise to/where store such properties?
Thank you

Comment: Store the watched IDs in the backend and also a local copy in the front end. If you serving the videos, then the check is done server side before sending the result back to the user, in that case you don't need a local copy.  I'm not sure of how your application  operates so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to get the same results from a different browser - you should persist it on the backend side. If not - then you can keep it on the FE side.